# OnCollisionStay at a time Collision detection for two plane in C# unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am a beginner and working in Stacker game and there are multiple planes, but one of them is true and other is false. Now my problem is that, sometimes stacker stops at two plane simultaneously and both function gets called on 'is game over' and other 'go to next level'. Tell me how can I compare two tags, that if both true then do something. thanks here is my code.

> 

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision) {

        if (collision.collider.tag == "plane1") {

            if (script2.rb.velocity.magnitude == 0.0f) {

                collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = color1;
                cont++;
                SetCountText ();
                script1.jump1 ();
                StartCoroutine (wait ());
            }

        } else if (collision.collider.tag == "plane2") {
            if (script2.rb.velocity.magnitude == 0.0f) {
                script.jump ();
                Time.timeScale = 0;
            }
            else {
                if (script2.rb.velocity.magnitude == 0.0f) {
                    script.jump ();
                    Time.timeScale = 0;
                }

            }


        }

      if (collision.collider.tag == "plane1" && collision.collider.tag ==    "plane2") {

            script.jump ();
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            Debug.Log("hello");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't entirely match your question, but I gather that the problem is that both the "win" and "lose" condition are triggered by physics, and both are happening in the same frame?

The most straightforward way to handle that is to have a bool (or better, an enum) to store the state of your game--if the level is over, the collision functions shouldn't do anything. It does seem like there should be a pretty, elegant way to solve this, but I'm not aware of one. Disabling the colliders probably won't work, since both collisions have already occurred by the time your physics callback functions are called.